# Modify the APK and upload it again

Tags: appgallery

While uploading apk to app gallery account I'm facing this error "The version number or version code parsed from the APK is incorrect. Please modify the APK and upload it again." Please guide me how to fix this.

Answer (score 2):

the version code is must b one number for example 1,2,3,4,10,100 etc
and version name must contain two dotes  , for example 1.0.0 , 1.0.10 , 1.1.25 ,3.3.50 etc
check in your project  build.Gradle file
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Issue could be due to improper obfuscated package. Please refer below link for proper configuration for obfuscation

https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides/android-config-obfuscation-scripts-0000001050176973